# Does Xcode have a navigate to file/class shortcut?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I want something like in textmate where I can quickly navigate to a file or class

Answer (score 48):

Command-Shift-O displays the "Quick Open" Window.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - I updated my answer for Xcode 4

Comment: You made my day! I've been using AppCode for the past 5 years and used the find class/file functionality every day. I was heartbroken when they end-of-lifed it because I didn't know Xcode could do this.

Answer (score 5):

The 'Quick Open' shortcut was changed to Command-Shift-o (that's the letter o and not zero) in XCode 4

Answer (score 1):

I don’t use TextMate, but maybe this is what you want: File -> Open Quickly… (or shift-command-D). Another useful shortcut is View -> Switch to Header/Source File (or option-command-up arrow) to switch between header file (.h) and source file (.m).

Comment: Quick Open is an amazing time saver, highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You can Cmd+Double click on an item to navigate there. Also, you can assign shortcut for either menu Edit->Find->Jump to Definition or Jump to Selection, but the behavior there is not accurate.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone finding this question years after it was asked, you can jump to a file by having your cursor on the class name and typing

`Cmd+^+J`